# Programmatically getting xml namespace in Android app

Tags: android, xml, namespaces

Android's `AttributeSet.getAttributeIntValue` takes `String namespace` as input. Hard coding the namespace seems like a bad idea, because if the namespace changes, then a runtime bug is introduced. More concretely, it would be nice to avoid

```
attrs.getAttributeIntValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto", 
                                                             "myAttribute", 0)
```

since it hard codes string `"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`, which seems unnecessary. (Admittedly, it hard codes `"myAttribute"`, but that seems unavoidable.) Is it possible to read the integer attribute `"myAttribute"` without hard coding the name space? (Possibly by naming the xml file that contains `"myAttribute"`.) Such that compilation errors are generated if anything goes wrong. (E.g., the file no longer exists.) Alternatively, is it possible to produce a compiler error if `"myAttribute"` cannot be found (this would eliminate the need for a default value too, since it would never be used).

**Context**. I have extended a `LinearLayout` to override constructors `LinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` and `LinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)`. These constructors use `AttributeSet.getAttributeIntValue` to read attributes from `attrs`. Thus, code and GUI are completely separate. However, if the namespace is changed in the GUI, then problems arise when the namespace is hardcoded in the code. (This actually happened. So, I'm trying to figure out how to avoid it happening again!)

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do ? seems like you are using `AttributeSet ` where you should use `TypedValue`

Comment: I've added some context to the question. I don't see how `TypedValue` is relevant to me...

Comment: if you need to read something from the attributes, TypedArray is the way to go, you shouldn't have to use AttributeSet directly

Comment: Given the `AttributeSet attrs` taken as input by the constructor, how can I recover a particular integer attribute using `TypedValue` or `TypedArray`? At present, I simply use `attrs.getAttributeIntValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto", "myAttribute", 0)`, where the first parameter is the name space, the second is the name of the attribute, and the third is the default. (This is undesirable, as per my question, because I hard code the namespace.)

Comment: Just to be sure before I do a complete answer, you have a custom attribute and you want to use it in your layout, that's it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a custom attribute for your view and want to use it in your code, you can follow the [documentation about custom views](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr). Basically, you declare your attributes in `styleable`, and then use `obtainResources` to get them.

Comment: I just want the namespace. E.g., I want to avoid `attrs.getAttributeIntValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto", "myAttribute", 0)`, since I hardcode `"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`. In an alternate direction, I'd be happy with a compiler error if "myAttribute" cannot be found.